# Alinhamento de botões com css

Tags: css

Bom tenho aqui os botões personalidades com CSS. Preciso que eles sempre fiquem no centro da pagina, se eu colocar vários botões eles tem que ficar em um fila no centro da página. E quando a tela for pequena eles vão criando uma quebra de linha.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso sem ter que colocar os botões dentro de uma tag?

```css
.text-white,
.text-white-houve:hover,
.bt {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
.shadow-1,
.bt,
.container {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.shadow-2,
.bt:hover,
.context_menu_pai,
.box_login,
.datepicker.dropdown-menu,
.dialogbox,
.overflow-menu ul {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.transition-1,
.bt {
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.bt {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button class='bt' type='submit'>OK</button>
<button class='bt' type='submit'>OK</button>
<button class='bt' type='submit'>OK</button>
<button class='bt' type='submit'>OK</button>
```

Comment: O botoes estao dentro de algum elemento sem ser o `<body>`?

Comment: @PanterA estão apenas no body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para alinhar no centro você vai ter que usar um elemento-pai.
Coloque os botões dentro de um `div`.

```css
div {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

O `width` pode ser qualquer tamanho, mas é obrigatório.

Agora para ter quebra de linha será necessário reduzir o `width` do elemento-pai com a ajuda de `@media-queries`, fazendo com que os botões se ajustem na vertical.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 330px) {
    div {
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```

Sobre o exemplo acima. Quando o browser for menor que 331px, o elemento-pai será reduzido, fazendo com que os botões gerem quebras de linha.

Comment: teria um exemplo de como fazer usando um elemento-pai?

Comment: Seria colocar os botões dentro de um `div`. E então alinha-los no centro da tela.

Comment: tem como editar sua resposta?

Comment: Tem sim. Feito.

Comment: Bom aqui não deu certo, ficou tudo em sima do outro. Isso só pode ocorrer se não houver espaço na tela.

Comment: Você precisa aumentar o `width` da div em relação ao tamanho dos botões. Cada botão possui 200px, então a div tem que ter pelo menos 800px para comportar todos na mesma linha (sem contar o `padding` e `margin` que também devem entrar na soma).

Answer (score 2):

Como seus botões estão com `display: block-inline`, o comportamento deles será semelhante a um elemento `inline`, ficando sujeitos a alinhamentos de texto. Então você pode adicionar a seguinte regra no elemento `body` para centralizar seus botões:

```
body {
   text-align: center
}
```

Nesse caso, o `text-align` vai afetar todos elementos `inline` dentro do `body`. Se quiser restringir isso aos botões, colocá-los dentro de uma `div` deve resolver seu problema:

```css
.bt-container { 
   text-align: center 
 }
.text-white,
.text-white-houve:hover,
.bt {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
.shadow-1,
.bt,
.container {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.shadow-2,
.bt:hover,
.context_menu_pai,
.box_login,
.datepicker.dropdown-menu,
.dialogbox,
.overflow-menu ul {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.transition-1,
.bt {
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.bt {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bt-container">
    <button class='bt' type='submit'>OK</button>
    <button class='bt' type='submit'>OK</button>
    <button class='bt' type='submit'>OK</button>
    <button class='bt' type='submit'>OK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: bom dessa forma todo o texto da página fica no centro. acho que a única forma de fazer isso e usando um div pai, como o @Rafael Mafra falou.

Comment: Sim. A forma mais facil é com uma div, e aplicar a regra do `text-align: center` na div. Fazendo dessa forma os botões vão se alocando e as quebras de linhas vão ocorrendo de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

Comment: Ok obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo sugiro que pesquise sobre "mobile first", isso vai fazer com que escreva muito menos e seu desenvolvimento fica mais "intuitivo".

Note aqui que eu adicionei a propriedade "display" com o valor "inline-block", isso faz com que os botoes herdem propridades de elementos block e nao irao ficar se sobrepondo quando voce adicionar um padding e houver uma quebra de linha.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #aaaaaa;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.container button:hover {
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>one</button>
  <button>two</button>
  <button>three</button>
  <button>four</button>
  <button>five</button>
</div>
```